# Media player for macOS with tabbed interface

Tags: osx, macos, video-player

Right now I'm using [IINA](https://iina.io/) as my media player. The problem with this player is that if I want to open multiple videos, I have to open every video in a new window which clutters the desktop.

Is there a media player that supports tabbed interface where I have only one main window and every new video is opened in a new tab inside the same window?

Free, open-source is preferable.

Comment: Found any software?

Comment: @ynn unfortunately no